# Configure Geoserver to use an external EPSG database

Tags: gis, geoserver, epsg

Geoserver uses en embedded HSQL database with EPSG codes to perform coordinates conversions.

(Ref: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/advanced/crshandling/manualepsg.html)

I am trying to find out how it can be configured to use an external database to load the EPSG codes, so that custom CRS can be maintained separately.

Please help.

Comment: what about http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/user/advanced/crshandling/customcrs.html

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement an extension similar to gt-epsg-postgresql-11.0.jar, and replace it in WEB-INF/lib. The extension has only one class that creates the datasource. In this case it would be a Mysql datasource instead of a postgresql one.